# SELECT Field if it exists on all DB tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sp-msforeachtable

I have an SQL Server DB with 100+ tables. Many, *but not all of them*, have a column called `ins_date` which is used to keep the date each record was inserted in the DB.

I would like to obtain the last (max) date of insertion for every table in my DB. I have done some tinkering with `sp_MSforeachtable` which seems good enough to iterate through all the tables.

**The problem I'm facing**: my queries will return error when they bump into a table that doesn't have the `ins_date` column. What can I use, together with `sp_MSforeachtable`, to obtain the info only from the tables that have `ins_date`, and just ignore or return as NULL the other tables?

Answer (score 0):

U can try this code for check null situation for a table

```
 string kyt = "SELECT * from sp_MSforeachtable where yourcondition=@yourcondition";
                                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(kyt, con);
                                con.Open();
                                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(@yourcondition,"valueofyourcondition");
                                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
                                SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
                                if (dr.Read())
                                {
                                    dr["ins_date"].ToString();


                                    if (dr["ins_date"] != DBNull.Value)
                                    {
```

Comment: you have answered in C# when the question had no tags or any reference to C#

Answer (score 0):

You might want to wrap the query in `@command1` with an if statement. Something like this:

```
if exists(select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where COLUMN_NAME = 'ins_date' and TABLE_NAME='?')
```